# Can I call the Twitter Link Service (for url shortening) programatically?

Tags: c#, api, twitter, url-shortener, twitterizer

I've just implemented a feature on my site to use the Twitterizer API in C# to make a tweet under a machine account whenever new user content is added to my site.

Works great, but if I call the Twitterizer Update() method directly and the tweet includes a URL, the URL is not getting run through Twitter's new URL shortening Link Serverice http://t.co

Here's the stub I'm currently using:

```
  public static void PostTweet(string text, string url)
  {
     OAuthTokens tokens = (OAuthTokens)HttpContext.Current.Application[AppCache.TwitterOAuthTokens];

     TwitterResponse<Twitterizer.TwitterStatus> tweetResponse = Twitterizer.TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, String.Format("New Prediktion: \"{0}\" {1}", text, url));
  }
```

Is there a Twitter API I can call to shorten up the URL? I was hoping this would happen automagically when I invoked Update(), but no such luck.  If not, what are my alternatives? I want both shorter URLs and clickable URLs in the tweet.

**EDIT:**

I guess the real question is: If I'm patient, will I eventually start getting shortened **and** clickable URL's in my tweets for free as the new...

> http://t.co

...service is rolled out?

Right now, if send the following text to the Twitter API, I just get a tweet with raw text, but no clickable URL:

```
string tweet = "Hey, check out this cool new site! http://real-cool-site.com";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's url shortener is applied automatically, but (according to [their support page](http://support.twitter.com/entries/109623)) is still being rolled out and may not be applied to every link.

You do not need to do anything to apply the shortened url and can expect the shortened url to be 19 characters long.

Comment: Also, I think tweets that have their links shortened with t.co will not show the full url in the tweet text returned by the API. It will return the tweet with the shortened url. The full url is available in the entities section so that you can display the long url (but you should still link to the short url for Twitter's analytics).

Comment: So, I'm calling into the Twitter API using Twitterizer, but none of my URL's (no matter how I craft them) are getting resolved as links.  They just show up as raw text.  If I create a link as follow: "Here is my cool tweet! http://www.coolsite.com" I see exactly that, but the URL is just plain text.  When I use the Twitter dialog on my site, I do get all the goodness from http://t.co, but not with API calls.

Comment: Heh! Well on this site, my link to http : // coolsite.com DOES get resolved, but not with the Twitter API.

Comment: You must construct a proper url, including http://. Twitter.com may apply some javascript logic to detect domain names and prepare them, but that isn't a function of the Twitter API. (By the way, I'm the author of Twitterizer.)

Comment: Cool, my daily Brush With Greatness!  Awesome tool, and I love the work that folks like you do with open source projects. I tried TwitterSharp (Twitter# ?) as well, but found I was able to get going with a "Hello, world!" function MUCH faster with Twitterizer.  That's my typical litmus test when trying out a new API.  I'm  properly constructing the URL, but Twitter is still treating URL's embedded in programmatic tweets as string literals, so they don't receive any special treatment or parsing.

Comment: I've accepted this response and the correct answer for me. I think I'll just need to be patient while Twitter's URL minifier is rolled out.  In the meantime, I'll be making tweets from my site the old fashioned way: manually. That'll guarantee that everything is normalized.  Of course, this won't be an option for us at http://ipredikt.com next week when we go viral, but it'll work OK this week...